# django rest framework cannot POST data

Tags: django, rest, post, frameworks, submit

I implemented a basic rest api with the django rest framework. It works perfectly using the browsable api or communicating to it with requests. Next step would be submitting data to the rest api.

Here is what I have done so far.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

**[UPDATE:]**
models.py

```
class Request(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Request, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

serializers.py

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

views.api

```
class RequestsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Request.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
```

Using the browsable api I see that those are the options supported:

```
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

Obviously, POST (and also PUT) is missing.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding the post method to the modelviewset (in the view):

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    ...
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you only need to call save method on the model object to persist the object in the database.

First, import model to the view, instantiate a model object in the view, then call save method on the newly created object. If you have model connected to the backend, that will persist your changes.

models.py

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from models import YourModel
def yourView(request):
   yourObject = YourModel(name='John') 
   yourObject.save()  
   ...
```

Check also Django documentation for models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/)

Comment: hi! I have updated the question (models.py). I added the save() method as you mentioned it. No change in behavior. still cant post new objects to the api.

Comment: You don't need to define a save method in the model - it's inherited from models.Model class. Second, Request class doesn't sound right. The classes in the models.py should be mapped to tables in the database. The HTTP request object is passed to the view. Inside the view you need to instantiate a model instance and call save method on it.